# Multiple conflicting route parameter formats in Razor Pages

Tags: razor-pages

I'm making simple crud forms based on the tutorials for Razor Pages MVVM - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1

The issue is the elements on the Index page use different formats for the route parameter and I end up with URL's like /StockIndexMonths/2?StockIndexId=1
Where both /2 and StockIndexId=1 are the same parameter

- The select list will use ?StockIndexId=1
- The Create New link will use /1, when returning to the Index /1 is used
- If I use the select list again I get both /1?StockIndexId=2

Can anyone tell me the preferred way to force the same parameter format to be used?  I'm trying to keep Razor Pages doing it's 'magic'

Index.cshtml

```
@page "{StockIndexId?}"
@model Investments.Pages.StockIndexMonths.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form>
    <select asp-for="StockIndexId" asp-items="Model.StockIndexNameSelect" onchange="this.form.submit();"></select>
</form>

    <a asp-page="Create" asp-route-StockIndexId="@Model.StockIndexId">Create New</a>

<table class="table">
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the form tag so that it uses the `POST` method:

`<form method="post">`

Currently, because the `method` is not specified, `GET` is used by default, which appends forms values to the URL as query string values. That's why you see what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It does solve the immediate issue, but it requires adding a OnPostAsync and duplicating the OnGetAsync code.  I think I'm better using javascript which is my current work around

Comment: You can centralise any page initialisation code, such as populating SelectLists, in the PageModel constructor instead of duplicating it in multiple handler methods.

Comment: Yes, but I would also need to duplicate the code to generate the main Index table (or use a central function).  I'm not posting a new item to be saved, just an ID for filtering.  Isn't a form GET the correct usage?  Respectfully, I'm trying to stick to the principles, or else I would have continued using Web Forms.  I still see the issue as Razor Pages is using 2 formats of parameter and I'd hope there is a way to force it to use 1.  If there isn't, a single javascript command seems as effective, with a lot less code, and staying 'restful'

Comment: A form submitted using GET will append values in the query string. That's how it works in Web Forms, MVC, PHP etc. Nothing to do with Razor Pages. Using JS to  pass the selected value in the URL format that you want is a good option. Or you can use the OnPost handler to do a RedirectToPage call

Comment: Thanks Mike, appreciate your help.  You did provide a working solution so I'll mark this as answered